# Windows Runtime app doesn't report any crashes

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

My app has crashes, but I don't see any reports in the dev center. When I create a package, there is an option

> "include public symbol files, if any, to enable crash analysis for the
>   app".

What are these files and how to know my app has any?

It's a Windows Phone Runtime app. thanks.

Comment: It takes about 5 days in my experience for a crash occurring on a device for it to show up in the dev center. The public symbol files give you the ability to debug the crash dump better after you get the dump.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like BugSense or Hockey app if you want to bug reports quicker

https://www.bugsense.com/

http://hockeyapp.net/features/

Comment: those services doesn't support Windows Phone Runtime apps at the moment